# How to read csv into a list and dictionary

Tags: python, csv, random

I want to create a game that displays a country and asks the user to enter the capital for the country displayed. After the user enters the capital, it will display another country and ask for the capital, and repeat the process until the user has answered the capital for ten countries. Then, display the users score at the end of the game. For each capital the user enters correctly, I want to award 5 points.

This is what I have done so far

```
import csv
import pandas
import random

african_countries = open("african_countries.csv", "r")
rd = csv.reader(african_countries)

def main():
    setupGame()
    playGame()
def setupGame():
    global countries, capitals, correct, incorrect, used
    correct = 0
    incorrect = 0
    used = [False] * 55
    countries = setupCountriesList()
    capitals = setupCapitalsDictionary()
    print("\nCOUNTRIES AND CAPITALS QUIZ!")

def playGame():
    global correct, incorrect, used
    guess = ""
    while guess.lower() != "quit":
        idx = random.randint(0, 9) 
        while used[idx]:
            idx = random.randint(0, 9) #To generate a new idx if already used
        used[idx] = True
        allTrue = True #check to see if all used is True
        for i in range(0,55):
            if used[i] == False:
                allTrue = False
        if allTrue:
            used = [False] * 55 #To reset all used to false
        country = countries[idx]
        capital = capitals[country]
        guess = input("What is the capital of " + country.upper() + "? (enter 'quit' to end)>> ")
        if guess.lower() =="quit":
            print("THANKS FOR PLAYING...You got {0} of {1} correct.\n".format(correct, (correct + incorrect)))
            break
        elif guess.lower() == capital.lower():
            print("CORRECT! {0} is the capital of {1}".format(capital, country))
            correct += 5
        else:
            print("SORRY... The capital of {0} is {1}".format(country, capital))
            incorrect += 5
        print("YOUR SCORE: You have gotten {0} of {1} correct \n".format(correct, (correct + incorrect)))

def setupCountriesList():
    countries = []
    for row in rd:
        countries.append(row[0])
    return countries

def setupCapitalsDictionary():  
    capitals = {}
    for row in rd:
        k, v = row
        capitals[k] = v
    return capitals

main()
```

But I got this error:

COUNTRIES AND CAPITALS QUIZ!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Gideon Markus/Desktop/Cyhermes/Week 4/Project 3/Python/trial.py", line 61, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:/Users/Gideon Markus/Desktop/Cyhermes/Week 4/Project 3/Python/trial.py", line 10, in main
    playGame()
  File "c:/Users/Gideon Markus/Desktop/Cyhermes/Week 4/Project 3/Python/trial.py", line 35, in playGame
    capital = capitals[country]
KeyError: 'The Republic of Cabo Verde'
PS C:\Users\Gideon Markus\Desktop\Cyhermes\Week 4\Project 3\Python>
```

Comment: First, try debugging it by printing out the countries list.  That way you know if you're feeding in the right strings into setupCountriesList().  Judging from that error, the countrylist isn't what you're expecting.

Comment: One hint to the above, you can call print() directly on your dict object. This should make troubleshooting the KeyError relatively straightforward.

Comment: One problem I think is that you are reading the csv file, `rd`, in `setupCountriesList()` and  `setupCapitalsDictionary()`. The file would be exhausted after reading it in the first function and would not be able to be used again in the second function.

Comment: @ChrisCharley that is one of the issues. It prints the first list but doesn't print the dictionary. Please how do it resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Doing this fixed the issue for me.

```
def setupCountriesList():
    with open(african_countries, "r") as country:
        rd = csv.reader(country)
        countries = []
        for row in rd:
            countries.append(row[0])
        return countries

def setupCapitalsDictionary():  
    with open(african_countries, "r") as capital:
        drd = csv.reader(capital)
        capitals = {}
        for row in drd:
            k, v = row
            capitals[k] = v
        return capitals
```

Comment: Yes, that works but why the 2 different functions when you could initialize both structures in 1 function instead of 2 functions?

Comment: I honestly have no idea how to achieve that. I will be grateful if you can help

Answer (score 0):

To collapse the 2 functions into 1, you might try:

```
def initialize_structs(african_countries):
    countries = []
    capitals = {}
    with open(african_countries, 'r') as f:
        rd = csv.reader(f)
        for row in rd:
            countries.append(row[0])
            capitals[row[0]] = row[1]

    return capitals, countries
```